# django model - message in save() method printed twice, but object saved once

Tags: python, django

I am using django 2.0.8 and Python 3.5. I have written a base class which encapsulates behavior in a base class.

When the object is saved, it's supposed to print a message ONCE. However, when I run code that is supposed to save the object, I get the message "fire of message" printed twice - why?

Here is my code:

```
class Likeable(models.Model):
    likes = GenericRelation(Like)


    def action_is_permissible(self, actionable_object, actor):
        ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(actionable_object)
        object_id = actionable_object.id
        found_objects = Like.objects.filter(content_type=ct, object_id=object_id, liker=actor)

        return ((len(found_objects) == 0), ct, object_id, found_objects)


    def add_like(self, actionable_object, actor):

        can_add, ct, object_id, found_objects = self.action_is_permissible(actionable_object, actor)

        print(can_add, ct, object_id, found_objects)

        if can_add:
            print('Save Called!')
            # Create like object and save it
            like = self.likes.create(content_type=ct, object_id=object_id, liker=actor)
            like.save()
        else:
            # do nothing
            print('Nothing doing')
            return


    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Foo(Likeable):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255,default='')
    objects = models.Manager()
```

### Example use (imports omitted)

```
foo = Foo.objects.get(id=1)
p = User.objects.get(id=1)

foo.add_like(foo, p) # <- nasty API calling convention, but I digress
```

### Console output

```
True foo 1 <QuerySet []>
Save Called!
Fire of like saved signal
Fire of like saved signal
```

Why is the message printed twice - when the object is saved only once in the db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
like = self.likes.create(content_type=ct, object_id=object_id, liker=actor)
like.save()
```

`QuerySet.create()` do actually call `save()` on the instance - else the method would just be a useless duplicate of the model's initializer -, so you indeed have two calls.